# I tried creating Tabs using Js and CSS but they won't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a college project that intends that I create a website only using HTML, CSS and Js. I'm trying to create a store and I wish to divide the products using tabs (just like pages) but for now I wasn't able to accomplish that, clicking on the buttons won't do anything.

I tried following the guide from w3schools.com but to no avail.

HTML:

```
<div class="options">

<div id="page1" class="tabcontent">
    <ul>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt486_a.jpg"></a>
            <div class="productinfo">
                <h2>
                    <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
                </h2>
                <div class="price">
                    <a href="#product">
                        <h2>60.00€</h2>
                    </a>                                
                </div>
                <div class="buybutton">
                    <button class="button">Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt504.jpg"></a>
            <div class="productinfo">
                <h2>
                    <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
                </h2>
                <div class="price">
                    <a href="#product">
                        <h2>60.00€</h2>
                    </a>                                
                </div>
                <div class="buybutton">
                    <button class="button">Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="page2" class="tabcontent">
    <ul>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt486_a.jpg"></a>
            <div class="productinfo">
                <h2>
                    <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
                </h2>
                <div class="price">
                    <a href="#product">
                        <h2>60.00€</h2>
                    </a>                                
                </div>
                <div class="buybutton">
                    <button class="button">Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt504.jpg"></a>
            <div class="productinfo">
                <h2>
                    <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
                </h2>
                <div class="price">
                    <a href="#product">
                        <h2>60.00€</h2>
                    </a>                                
                </div>
                <div class="buybutton">
                    <button class="button">Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab">
    <h1>
        <button class="tabbutton" onclick="openPage(event, 'page1')" id="defaultOpen">1</button> |
        <button class="tabbutton" onclick="openPage(event, 'page2')">2</button>
    </h1>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tab {
border: solid red;
width: 95%;
}

.tab h1 {
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
border: solid black;
padding-left: 48%;
font-size: 30px;
}

.tab button {
border: none;
background-color: white;
font-size: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.tab button:hover {
background-color: black;
color: white;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.tab button.active {
background-color: black;
color: white;

}

.tabcontent {
display: none;
}
```

Js:

```
function openPage(evt, pageNum) {
  var i, tabbutton, tabcontent;
  tabcontent = document.getElementByClassName("tabcontent");
  tabbutton = document.getElementByClassName("tabbutton");

  for (i = 0; i<tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i<tabbutton.length; i++) {
    tabbutton[i].className = tabbutton[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(pageNum).style.display="block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

In the end it won't work when I click the buttons, the divs that were supposed to appear won't be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change a small changes in your code i have written down the answer here for you. IF you wan to know what the error was the error was ' **getElementByClassName**'
its **s** in Element **getElementsByClassName**

```js
function openPage(evt, pageNum) {
  var i, tabbutton, tabcontent;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  tabbutton = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbutton");

  for (i = 0; i<tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i<tabbutton.length; i++) {
    tabbutton[i].className = tabbutton[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(pageNum).style.display="block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
.tab h1 {
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
border: solid black;
padding-left: 48%;
font-size: 30px;
}

.tab button {
border: none;
background-color: white;
font-size: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.tab button:hover {
background-color: black;
color: white;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.tab button.active {
background-color: black;
color: white;

}
.tab {
border: solid red;
width: 95%;
}

.tabcontent {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="options">

<div id="page1" class="tabcontent">
    <ul>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt486_a.jpg"></a>
            <div class="productinfo">
                <h2>
                    <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
                </h2>
                <div class="price">
                    <a href="#product">
                        <h2>60.00€</h2>
                    </a>                                
                </div>
                <div class="buybutton">
                    <button class="button">Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt504.jpg"></a>
            <div class="productinfo">
                <h2>
                    <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
                </h2>
                <div class="price">
                    <a href="#product">
                        <h2>60.00€</h2>
                    </a>                                
                </div>
                <div class="buybutton">
                    <button class="button">Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="page2" class="tabcontent">
    <ul>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt486_a.jpg"></a>
            <div class="productinfo">
                <h2>
                    <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
                </h2>
                <div class="price">
                    <a href="#product">
                        <h2>60.00€</h2>
                    </a>                                
                </div>
                <div class="buybutton">
                    <button class="button">Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt504.jpg"></a>
            <div class="productinfo">
                <h2>
                    <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
                </h2>
                <div class="price">
                    <a href="#product">
                        <h2>60.00€</h2>
                    </a>                                
                </div>
                <div class="buybutton">
                    <button class="button">Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab">
    <h1>
        <button class="tabbutton" onclick="openPage(event, 'page1')" id="defaultOpen">1</button> |
        <button class="tabbutton" onclick="openPage(event, 'page2')">2</button>
    </h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not getElementByClassName but getElementsByClassName with gives us an array.

Answer (score 1):

TRy using the below code, you will be able to run the code. There is a typo in  "getElementByClassName"

```js
function openPage(evt, pageNum) {
  var i, tabbutton, tabcontent;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  tabbutton = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbutton");

  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < tabbutton.length; i++) {
    tabbutton[i].className = tabbutton[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(pageNum).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
.tab {
  border: solid red;
  width: 95%;
}

.tab h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  border: solid black;
  padding-left: 48%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.tab button {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="options">

    <div id="page1" class="tabcontent">
      <ul>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt486_a.jpg"></a>
          <div class="productinfo">
            <h2>
              <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
            </h2>
            <div class="price">
              <a href="#product">
                <h2>60.00€</h2>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="buybutton">
              <button class="button">Buy</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt504.jpg"></a>
          <div class="productinfo">
            <h2>
              <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
            </h2>
            <div class="price">
              <a href="#product">
                <h2>60.00€</h2>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="buybutton">
              <button class="button">Buy</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="page2" class="tabcontent">
      <ul>
        Tab 2 Content
        <li class="item">
          <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt486_a.jpg"></a>
          <div class="productinfo">
            <h2>
              <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
            </h2>
            <div class="price">
              <a href="#product">
                <h2>60.00€</h2>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="buybutton">
              <button class="button">Buy</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt504.jpg"></a>
          <div class="productinfo">
            <h2>
              <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
            </h2>
            <div class="price">
              <a href="#product">
                <h2>60.00€</h2>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="buybutton">
              <button class="button">Buy</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tab">
      <h1>
        <button class="tabbutton" onclick="openPage(event, 'page1')" id="defaultOpen">1</button> |
        <button class="tabbutton" onclick="openPage(event, 'page2')">2</button>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `getElementByClassName` to `getElementsByClassName`...

```js
function openPage(evt, pageNum) {
  var i, tabbutton, tabcontent;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  tabbutton = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbutton");

  for (i = 0; i<tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i<tabbutton.length; i++) {
    tabbutton[i].className = tabbutton[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(pageNum).style.display="block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
.tab {
border: solid red;
width: 95%;
}

.tab h1 {
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
border: solid black;
padding-left: 48%;
font-size: 30px;
}

.tab button {
border: none;
background-color: white;
font-size: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.tab button:hover {
background-color: black;
color: white;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.tab button.active {
background-color: black;
color: white;

}

.tabcontent {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="options">

<div id="page1" class="tabcontent">
    <ul>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt486_a.jpg"></a>
            <div class="productinfo">
                <h2>
                    <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
                </h2>
                <div class="price">
                    <a href="#product">
                        <h2>60.00€</h2>
                    </a>                                
                </div>
                <div class="buybutton">
                    <button class="button">Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt504.jpg"></a>
            <div class="productinfo">
                <h2>
                    <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
                </h2>
                <div class="price">
                    <a href="#product">
                        <h2>60.00€</h2>
                    </a>                                
                </div>
                <div class="buybutton">
                    <button class="button">Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="page2" class="tabcontent">
    <ul>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt486_a.jpg"></a>
            <div class="productinfo">
                <h2>
                    <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
                </h2>
                <div class="price">
                    <a href="#product">
                        <h2>60.00€</h2>
                    </a>                                
                </div>
                <div class="buybutton">
                    <button class="button">Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#product"><img src="loja/roupa/topproducts/avt504.jpg"></a>
            <div class="productinfo">
                <h2>
                    <a href="#product" class="productname">
                        The Avett Brothers<br/>
                        Bowen Hoodie
                    </a>
                </h2>
                <div class="price">
                    <a href="#product">
                        <h2>60.00€</h2>
                    </a>                                
                </div>
                <div class="buybutton">
                    <button class="button">Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab">
    <h1>
        <button class="tabbutton" onclick="openPage(event, 'page1')" id="defaultOpen">1</button> |
        <button class="tabbutton" onclick="openPage(event, 'page2')">2</button>
    </h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have just to replace  `getElementByClassName` with `getElementsByClassName` in line 3,4 find the code [here](https://196352.playcode.io/) 
and its will working fine, i would suggest that , using bootstrap will help you and make your life easier,